# How to do multiple posts with one button

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am working with the following code(invoice.php), and it posts inventory data into "invoice" under a table called "invoices".  I want to add a category called "salesman" under "invoices", and insert code that will coincide with the form post code in this page.  Does anyone know how I can insert both at the same time?

```
<?php 
    $user_obj = new Cl_User();
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        try {
            $user_obj->saveInvoice($_POST);
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Invoice Saved Successfully!';
            header('Location: invoices.php');exit;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }elseif (isset($_GET['uuid']) && !empty($_GET['uuid'])){
        try {
            $results = $user_obj->getInvoice( $_GET['uuid'] );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }elseif (isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
        try {
            if( $user_obj->deleteInvoice( $_GET['delete'] )){
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Invoice Deleted Successfully!';
                header('Location: invoices.php');exit;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Invoice Not Deleted, Try Again!';
                header('Location: invoices.php');exit;
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $settings = $user_obj->getSettings();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r( $settings ); echo "</pre>";
    $invoice = array();
    if(!empty( $results )){
        $invoice = json_decode( $results['invoice'], true);
    }
?>


    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container content-invoice">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="invoice-form" method="post"  class="invoice-form" role="form" novalidate> 
            <div class="load-animate">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo isset($results['id']) ? $results['id']: ''; ?>" name="data[id]">
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8'>

                    </div>

                    <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
                        <input data-loading-text="Saving Workorder..." type="submit" name="invoice_btn" value="Save Workorder" class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-top form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                                    <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                                    <th width="15%">Item No</th>
                                    <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Price</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php if(isset($invoice['data']['Invoice'])&&!empty($invoice['data']['Invoice'])){?>
                                    <?php foreach ( $invoice['data']['Invoice']['itemNo'] as $key=>$item){?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['Invoice']['itemNo'][$key]) ? $invoice['data']['Invoice']['itemNo'][$key]: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][itemNo][]" id="itemNo_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['Invoice']['itemName'][$key]) ? $invoice['data']['Invoice']['itemName'][$key]: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][itemName][]" id="itemName_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['Invoice']['price'][$key]) ? $invoice['data']['Invoice']['price'][$key]: ''; ?>" type="number" name="data[Invoice][price][]" id="price_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['Invoice']['quantity'][$key]) ? $invoice['data']['Invoice']['quantity'][$key]: ''; ?>" type="number" name="data[Invoice][quantity][]" id="quantity_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['Invoice']['total'][$key]) ? $invoice['data']['Invoice']['total'][$key]: ''; ?>" type="number" name="data[Invoice][total][]" id="total_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php }else{?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][itemNo][]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][itemName][]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][price][]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][quantity][]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][total][]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>


                        <div class='form-group text-center'>
                            <input data-loading-text="Saving Invoice..." type="submit" name="invoice_btn" value="Save Workorder" class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-btm"/>
                        </div>

                    </div>

        </form>         
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/auto.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.submit_btn').on('click', function(){
            $(this).button('loading');
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.currency').html( $('#currency').val() );
        });

        $('#clientCompanyName').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'ajax.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type: 'customerName'
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            var code = item.split("|");
                                return {
                                    label: code[1],
                                    value: code[1],
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
            },
            autoFocus: true,            
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
                $(this).val(names[1]);
                getClientAddress(names[0]);
            }               
        });
        function getClientAddress(id){

             $.ajax({
                 url: "ajax.php",
                 method: 'post', 
                 data:{id:id, type:'clientAddress'},
                 success: function(result){
                    $("#clientAddress").html(result);
                }
            });
        }





    </script>

     <?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
     <?php 
     unset($_SESSION['success'] );
     unset($_SESSION['error']);
     ?> 

     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what the giant wall of code is for but you need to loop through the POST data twice and perform your desired insert. Any further information will cost you $150 per hour with a 4 hour minimum.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I probably overkilled the code post, but if I just post a tidbit, people ask for more, so whatever....  What do you mean I need to loop through the POST code twice, why can I not post everything once?

Comment: Could you please try to clarify what it is you want to accomplish? What do you mean by creating a "category"? What is it that you want to insert and into what?

Comment: Hint: find `$user_obj->saveInvoice($_POST);` and alter the code to also insert "salesman"

Comment: @Anders There is a column called "invoice" that everything else is inserted into, I want to insert into another column I have created called "salesman"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You are awesome!! Found out that $user_obj is linked to a file(user.php) That contains the sql statements.  The code I am using has the variables linked in a public function, so now all I have to do is figure out how to dynamically insert a variable, say $salesman into the form code so that it will show up in the same post statement, and then just alter user.php so that it will pass $salesman into the database.

Comment: @Steven Sounds like you are on the right track! Good luck!